# Finding node in xml by attribute that starts with string

Tags: c#, xml

I have large xml. The xml's nodes have attribute id with valus like this: "1_32434", "2_45656". With this code:

```
var node = myXml.XPathSelectElement(string.Format("//*[starts-with(@id,\"{0}_\"))", someValue));
```

I am trying to find all nodes that have attribute id that start with "someValue_", but I get error that there is an invalid token.

Comment: One `[` opens, none closes.

Comment: Note that this is subject to injection: it will fail no matter what if `someValue` contains a double quote. Be sure to validate your input, or write the query as code instead (`myXml.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(e => (e.Attribute("id")?.Value ?? "").StartsWith(someValue))`).

Answer (score 0):

There is an mismatch between opened and closed brackets, try to replace the last ')' by ']'

```
string.Format("//*[starts-with(@id,\"{0}_\")]", someValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not proud of this xpath. But it should give you all the nodes irregardless of starting id. If you only need for one id at a time. you should just add an ending bracket to your current xpath.

```
"//*[number(substring-before(@id,"_"))<10 and number(substring-after(@id,"_"))]"
```

some example XML would be greatly appreciated.